# Create user profile programmatically

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I want to overwrite the existing user profile that are in sp with my own one.

```
public string AccountName { get; set; }

public string WorkPhone { get; set; }

public string Department { get; set; }

public string Title { get; set; }

public string DistinguishedName { get; set; }

public string WorkEmail { get; set; }

public string Office { get; set; }



        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public void Create()
        {

            string socialDataStatsSite = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;

            using (SPSite siteColl = new SPSite(socialDataStatsSite))
            {

                SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(siteColl);

                UserProfileManager userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);

                UserProfile newProfile = userProfileManager.CreateUserProfile(AccountName, AccountName);

                newProfile[PropertyConstants.WorkPhone].Add(WorkPhone);

                newProfile[PropertyConstants.Department].Add(Department);

                newProfile[PropertyConstants.Title].Add(Title);

                newProfile[PropertyConstants.DistinguishedName].Add(AccountName);

                newProfile[PropertyConstants.Office].Add(Office);

                newProfile.Commit();

            }
        }
```

i have put this code in visual studio and deployed it.

Were do i find it in sharepoint to activate it?

Comment: What did you deploy this as? a feature? a web part?

Comment: @Ryan Erickson hi, in a webpart?

Comment: If it's in a webpart, then add the web part to a page..

Answer (score 0):

Create a Console Application & run the same or deploy as a feature & activate on the site.